# WhatsApp media missing, not on either new nor old phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, files

I really hope someone can help me.

I have recently bought a new phone and when I logged into WhatsApp on my new phone, the files weren't restored.

What's more upsetting is that I can't find WhatsApp folder with all my files, including very important images, on my old phone.

I've seen all kinds of suggestions online, including reinstalling WhatsApp and restoring all over but
I'm afraid to do anything now in fear I might lose my files forever!

How can I get access to my files?

They don't even have to be available in the WhatsApp on my new phone, I just want to have files somewhere, on my laptop.

Couple of things that might be relevant:

1. My old phone was Galaxy S10, my new phone is S23, so when I got the new phone, I used SmartSwitch to transfer the apps but not the files.

I was hoping to go through all the photos and videos and delete stuff I don't want to have transferred, so my new phone is clutter free.

Now the files are gone on my old phone! I've tried logging back into the old phone to see if WhatsApp media folder would appear in the gallery but it didn't.

2. My WhatsApp backed up regularly overnight to a Google Drive account but recently that Drive reached capacity so I changed it to another account so I'm not 100% sure where the bulk of the files is.

I know there are loads of questions like these but I'm too panicked to trial and fail. I've lost some family members in the past several years/months and there could be some mementos amongst the files. You just forget they're there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Having backups is must. If the files are important you shouldn't rely on the app itself and in any case, before transitioning, you should've saved them elsewhere, locally or at a cloud service.